# Flutter Bluetooth device is not connecting

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on Bluetooth device connecting functionality, where I am getting list of available devices around me, but I am won't be able to connect device once click on it. I may getting error which is following.

Error connecting to device:

```
FlutterBluePlusException | connect | android-code: 133 | ANDROID_SPECIFIC_ERROR
```

I am facing this error please any one help me out.

Following is my sample code:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';
 import 'package:hydration_monitor/Helper/CustomWidgets.dart';
 import 'dart:io' show Platform;

 class BluetoothScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const BluetoothScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<BluetoothScreen> createState() => _BluetoothScreenState();
 }

class _BluetoothScreenState extends State<BluetoothScreen> {

 bool isScan = false;
 List deviceDataSend =[];
 BluetoothDevice? connectedDevice;
```

Here is the code for scan other device:

```
void startScanning() async {
deviceDataSend.clear();
setState(() {
  isScan = true;
});
await FlutterBluePlus.startScan();
FlutterBluePlus.onScanResults.listen((results) {
  for (ScanResult result in results) {
    bool isDuplicate = deviceDataSend.any((device) => device['remoteId'] == result.device.remoteId);
    if (!isDuplicate) {
      if (!deviceDataSend.contains(result.device)) {
        setState(() {
          deviceDataSend.add(result.device);
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
}
```

Stop scan code:

```
stopScan()async{
setState(() {
  isScan = false;
});
await FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
}
```

Here is the my code for connect devide...!
device is holding data like --> BluetoothDevice{remoteId: 7F:C2:CF:AC:00:C9, platformName:'abc' , services: null}

```
connectDevice(BluetoothDevice device)async{

try {
  await device.connect();
} catch (e) {
  print("Error connecting to device: $e");
}
}
```

Following is basic code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Scaffold(
  appBar: BaseAppBar(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    title: CustomLabelText(Text: "BluetoothScreen",bgColor: Colors.white,size: _width / 22,Bold: true),
  ),
  body: BgContainer(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _width / 25),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: _height / 35,),
              isScan ? CustomButton(Text: 'Stop', width: 3, button: (){stopScan();},) :
              CustomButton(Text: 'Pair', width: 3, button: (){startScanning();},),
              SizedBox(height: _height / 35,),
              Divider(),
              Container(
                height: _height / 1.5,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: deviceDataSend.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      onTap: (){
                        connectDevice(deviceDataSend[index]);
                      },
                      title: CustomLabelText(
                        Text: deviceDataSend[index]['remoteId'].toString(),
                      ),
                      trailing: CustomLabelText(
                        Text: deviceDataSend[index]['platformName'],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: The Android error 133 is a well known generic error that does not really tell anything about what's going wrong. Sometimes even retrying helped for me in that occasions. Do you get any more logs or info from your app?

Comment: D/BluetoothGatt(10608): onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=10 device=D3:28:08:31:56:42
D/[FBP-Android](10608): [FBP] onConnectionStateChange: status: 133 (ANDROID_SPECIFIC_ERROR) newState: disconnected
D/BluetoothGatt(10608): close()
D/BluetoothGatt(10608): unregisterApp() - mClientIf=10
I/flutter (10608): Error connecting to device: FlutterBluePlusException | connect | android-code: 133 | ANDROID_SPECIFIC_ERROR  @MichaelKotzjan

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the errors there? Quite hard to read as a comment